# Video problem in refresh rate

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

thanks for coming.

I've experienced a strange video problem since I installed Ubuntu. I do not know exactly what is happening, but I think, after a deep research that it's a refresh problem.

In every video/film/youtube I watch, or game that I play, the movements looks gross. The FPS is always high (60 or above) but when a fast action happens the video doesn't follow the movement in a normal way, it's as if the FPS drops, but it doesn't!!

The most close demonstration of my problem is this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/3E9dTm4SCiA?t=9s)

Here is the result of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768      60.07*+  48.06  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    5.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected
```

Informations:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial 64-bit
- I tried commands like `xrandr -r 75` and nothing helped
- Intel Core i7-6500U
- Nvidia Geforce 930M - [Drivers Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBHVH.jpg)

English is not my native language and it's my first time in the forum, so I apologize for any mistake

Thanks for the attention, have a nice day

Comment: And you have the same issues with the video playback using different software (youtube in different browsers, playing files with VLC etc.) ???

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know how to answer because i can't do that tests. Two days after this post the computer showed me [this error](https://imgur.com/ZJIkYdZ)

After a research i concluded it was more easy to install windows in place of linux than fix this graphic card issue (wich, by the way, was caused by my imprudence on running terminal commands) Thanks again for the reply. I need no more help for now.

But it's never goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Guys the problem was VSYNC.What was happening was screen tearing, but i didn't even knew what it was kkk

So, i just looked up on some forums about how to enable vsync on nvidia graphics card, and it works. Now i can play sooo smoothly.

I can't remember how i did it tough, but i edited some text xorg thing and it worked, pretty easy